# SimpleXML serialization of list of objects

Tags: java, xml, serialization, simple-framework

I'm trying to serialize objects of a HealthCase class using SimpleXML. I'm able to correctly serialize everything, except for the ArrayList of Test objects, and the ArrayList of Image objects each Test object has. All classes have the appropriate accessor and mutator methods for each of their fields, but when I try to serialize, various xml composite write errors are thrown and the associated XML file is not written.

The HealthCase class (excluding methods):

```
@Root
public class HealthCase {
@Element
private String start; //age, chief complaint
@Element
private History history;
@Element
private String physicalState;
@Element
private String diagnosis;
@ElementList(inline=true)
private ArrayList<Test> tests;
```

The Test class (excluding methods):

```
@Element
public class Test {
@ElementList(required = false,inline=true)
private ArrayList<Image> images;
@ElementList(required=false)
private ArrayList<String> results;
@Element
private String name;
```

The image class (excluding methods):

```
@Element
public class Image{
@Element(required=false)
private String description;
@Element(required = false)
private String name;
@Element(required = false)
private Test relatedTest;
```

What are the XML tags I should use under the Test and Image classes (if any)? Should I make any changes to the HealthCase/Test/Image class's XML tags? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `circular dependency`.

Your `Test` class has List of `Images`, and in turn `Image` has reference to `Test` class.

Comment: Should I remove @Element(required = false)private Test relatedTest; then? It's not really necessary as is. Are the @Element tags above the public class Image and public class Test correct?

Comment: Thanks, getting rid of @Element(required = false)private Test relatedTest; did the trick!